# Is minimizing the sum of the reciprocals equivalent to maximizing the sum of the non-reciprocals, when the variables are coupled?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, semidefinite-programming

Let $G_i \in \mathbb{R}^{n_i \times n_i}$ for all $i \in [1...m]$ and $x_i \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $i \in [1...m]$. Consider the semidefinite program $$\min_{G_i\succeq0,~x_i\geq 0, \forall i\in [1...m]}\sum_{i=1}^m\frac{1}{x_i}\,,$$
subject to $$\begin{cases}G_i \succeq x_i I_{n_i}~\forall i \in [1...m]\\
\begin{bmatrix}\text{blkdiag}(G_1,...,G_m)& H^T\\ H&\sum_{i=1}^{m}x_i\end{bmatrix}\succeq 0
\end{cases}$$
for some matrix $H \in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times \sum_{i=1}^mn_i}$. Can I equivalently state the objective function as

$$\max_{G_i\succeq0,~x_i\geq 0, \forall i\in [1...m]}\sum_{i=1}^mx_i?$$

The idea would be that minimizing the sum of the reciprocals seems equivalent to maximizing the sum of the non-reciprocals. However, I'm concerned about the constraints, which somewhat couple the $x_i$'s together. If it is not equivalent, what assumptions do I need on the constraints?

Here you can find a similar question for the simpler case where the $x_i$'s belong to separate sets: [minimizing the sum of reciprocals is equivalent to maximizing the sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2733171/minimizing-the-sum-of-reciprocals-is-equivalent-to-maximizing-the-sum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but since you are working in the semidefinite programming world, you can just as well introduce new variables $z_i$ with $z_i \geq \frac{1}{x_i}$ which is SOCP-representable as it is equivalent to $\left|\left| \begin{matrix}x_i-y_i\\2\end{matrix} \right|\right| \leq x_i+y_i$, and then minimize $\sum z_i$ instead.

Comment: Thank you very much, this solves my first issue. I still have one issue in my SDP formulation, which I posted here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2733702/reformulation-of-nonlinear-optimization-problem-as-an-semi-definite-program-sdp

Would be great if you can have a look at it. Regards