# Reformulation of nonlinear optimization problem as a semidefinite program (SDP)

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, semidefinite-programming

Let $G \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $H \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times n}$ and $x_i \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $i \in [1...m]$ be decision variables. Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{p \times p}$ be a known invertible matrix. Consider the problem $$\min_{G\succeq 0,~x_i\geq 0, \forall i \in [1...m]} \sum_{i=1}^m \frac{1}{x_i}$$ $$\begin{bmatrix}G& H^T\\ H&A\left(\sum_{i=1}^{m}\frac{1}{x_i}\right)^{-1}\end{bmatrix}\succeq 0.$$

Can this be equivalently reformulated as a SDP?

A first step can be to add the SOCP constraint 
$$|| \begin{bmatrix}x_i-z_i&2\end{bmatrix}||_2\leq x_i+z_i\,,$$
so that $z_i \geq \frac{1}{x_i}$ and the problem becomes

$$\min_{G\succeq 0,~x_i\geq 0,~z_i,~\forall i \in [1...m]} \sum_{i=1}^m z_i$$ $$\begin{bmatrix}G& H^T\\ H&A\left(\sum_{i=1}^{m}z_i\right)^{-1}\end{bmatrix}\succeq 0.$$ $$|| \begin{bmatrix}x_i-z_i&2\end{bmatrix}||_2\leq x_i+z_i\,, \forall i \in [1...m]\,.$$

Is it possible to remove the nonlinearity in $z_i$ in the positive-semidefinite matrix?

Comment: You should be minimizing $z_i$, they are upper bounds on the terms you want to  minimize

Comment: Correct, sorry I mistyped.

Comment: Are both $G$ and $H$ functions of $x$?

Comment: Yes, G is coupled with $x_i$ through other constraints. H and G are also coupled through other constraints. By "coupled" I mean there are other constraints which involve G and x together, and G and H together. These constraints I didn't write are standard SDP constraints.

Comment: Depending on what you want to achieve it may or may not be helpful to  directly write $z\leq (\sum_i\frac{1}{x_i})^{-1}$ using SOCP (at least when $x_i>0$) https://themosekblog.blogspot.dk/2018/03/harmonic-mean-p-norms-and-extremely.html

Comment: Yes, the nonlinear term in the matrix inequality should be adressed by lower bounding an harmonic mean construction

Comment: Interesting. How can I express $t^2\leq x_i y_i$ in the standard SOCP form $||Av+b||_2 \leq c^Tv+d$, where $v=\text{col}(t,x_i,y_i)$?

Comment: norm([x-y;2*t]) <= x+y (sorry for the notation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ denote the harmonic mean. The objective is a scaled inverse of the harmonic mean, hence you are effectively maximizing the harmonic mean (which is concave and SOCP representable). Similarily, the term in the constraint is also the harmonic mean divided by $m$. An equivalent hypograph model is

$$\max t$$ $$\begin{bmatrix}G& H^T\\ H&A\frac{t}{m}\end{bmatrix}\succeq 0, f(x) \geq t$$

Comment: Thank you. the harmonic mean can be represented as $$t^2\leq 2x_i y_i~\forall i,~~2\sum_{i=1}^m y_i==t$$. I can express  $t^2\leq 2x_i y_i$ as $[t~x_i~y_i]M[t~x_i~y_i]'\leq 0$ where $M=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&-1\\0&-1&0\end{bmatrix}$, which is not positive semi-definite. How can I express it with a positive definite matrix?

Comment: @pinochino see [this paper](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/publications/socp.pdf). Johan, it's called 'SOCO' now ;)

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. Would $||[2t~~x_i-y_i]||_2\leq x+y$ be correct?

Comment: Correction: $||[\sqrt{2}t~~x_i−y_i]||_2≤x_i+y_i$

Comment: @LinAlg it will always be SOCP to me... old dog, new tricks, etc

Comment: Yes, I have not heard of a referendum to start calling it SOCO either. Or LO, QO, SDO, GO, MILO, NLO,...

Comment: We already lost the war on NLP. The "real" NLP doesn't even merit a mention https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NLP .